# unable to track the notification action in ionic | capacitor for "@capacitor/push-notifications"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I am unable to track notification action when application is in killed and background state in the ionic 7 with capacitor, Angular.

Here is my listeners code for action perform when notification received and click performed.

`PushNotifications.addListener(
'pushNotificationReceived',
async (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
alert("pushNotificationReceived");
console.log('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
const data = notification?.data;
if(data?.redirect) this._redirect.next(data?.redirect);
}
);

```
PushNotifications.addListener(
  'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
  async (notification:ActionPerformed) => {
    alert("pushNotificationActionPerformed");
    const data = notification.notification.data;
    console.log('Action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification.notification));
    console.log('push data: ', data);
    if(data?.redirect) this._redirect.next(data?.redirect);
  }
);`
```

Need to redirect on particular page or open when application is in killed and background state.
also detect the tap on the push notification.